# Google People API detect merged contacts with syncToken - previousResourceNames not included

Tags: google-people-api

I am using the people API to allow users to create entities in my system from their google contacts, via the people API, and am storing the resourceName (i.e 'people/c7760106965272617307') to keep track of the google contact the entity was created from.

I want to be able periodically update the entities to match what is in google. i.e. if the contact updates the phone number the entity gets the updated phone number. So am a calling the list API passing the sync token to get the contacts that have changed since the last call. This works for updates, edits and deletes but I can't find a way to detect when two contacts have been merged in google contacts.

The docs state:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.PersonMetadata

> previousResourceNames[] Any former resource names this person has had.
>   Populated only for connections.list requests that include a sync
>   token.

So if I:
 - Call the list API requesting a sync token
 - Create Contact A and Contact B
 - Call the list API passing the sync token, then I get just the two created contacts and a new sync token:

```
{
      "resourceName": "people/c1465347538402693914",
      "etag": "%EgcBAj0JPjcuGgQBAgUHIgxab0lZTFBvUU43bz0=",
      "metadata": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "CONTACT",
            "id": "1455f5d28afc531a",
            "etag": "#ZoIYLPoQN7o=",
            "updateTime": "2020-02-26T15:35:34.021Z"
          }
        ],
        "objectType": "PERSON"
      },
      "names": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "1455f5d28afc531a"
            }
          },
          "displayName": "Contact A",
          "familyName": "A",
          "givenName": "Contact",
          "displayNameLastFirst": "A, Contact"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceName": "people/c4555919836853785218",
      "etag": "%EgcBAj0JPjcuGgQBAgUHIgx2WmJHUUtjNTcxQT0=",
      "metadata": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "CONTACT",
            "id": "3f39e0f40cd35282",
            "etag": "#vZbGQKc571A=",
            "updateTime": "2020-02-26T15:35:44.056Z"
          }
        ],
        "objectType": "PERSON"
      },
      "names": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "3f39e0f40cd35282"
            }
          },
          "displayName": "Contact B",
          "familyName": "B",
          "givenName": "Contact",
          "displayNameLastFirst": "B, Contact"
        }
    }
```

If I then merge the two contacts, and then call the API passing the new sync token i get:

```
{
      "resourceName": "people/c4555919836853785218",
      "etag": "%EgcBAj0JPjcuGgQBAgUHIgxqNlFVYnIwaU9vVT0=",
      "metadata": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "CONTACT",
            "id": "3f39e0f40cd35282"
          }
        ],
        "deleted": true,
        "objectType": "PERSON"
      }
    }
```

**So TDLR;** I can find out one of the contacts were deleted, but not that it was merged into another contact.

It seems like the previousResourceNames[] field would do exactly what I want, but I can't seem to make it return in the data, either on the try the API function on the docs:

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list

or using the below nodjs code:

```
const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth: authClient});
const result = await service.people.connections.list({
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,metadata',
    //requestSyncToken: true
    syncToken: "insert token here"
});
console.info("Google Returned", JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 4));
```

I wonder if i need to grant extra scopes, or something else in the requested person fields.

Scopes Requested:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
```

Comment: Someone on stackoverflow received a response about `previousResourceNames` and, apparently, it *was* only used under specific conditions, so probably not what you want. Did the merged contact keep the name of 'A'? I would assume the `resourceName` of 'A' didn't changed and doesn't appear in the updates because none of its fields were modified? Have you tried merging two contacts with disjoint fields, for example 'A' with a phoneNumber and 'B' with a note/biography?